# Getting a newsapi data

Tags: javascript

I try to use https://newsapi.org new api

```
fetch(new Request('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines....')).then(function(response) {
    var json = response.json();
    console.log(json);//It gives 'Promise {<resolved>: {…}}'
    console.log(json.Promise//not work
    console.log(json.Promise['[[promiseValue]]']);//not work
});
```

How to get a json.Promise['']['[[promiseValue]]']?
Thank you for responses

Comment: I think you are missing (mode: 'no-cors') in your request.
Otherwise response.json() should work fine. you don't need json.Promise and all.

Comment: @RonnWilder — Adding `mode: 'no-cors'` means "I don't want to do anything with this request that requires permission from CORS, don't throw any errors about CORS". Since reading data from a different origin requires permission from CORS and the entire point of this request is to read data from a different origin … the net result of your suggestion will be to make it **fail silently** so **don't do that**!

Comment: What are you getting in response? can you post that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [the MDN guide to Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

> ```
> fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
>   .then(function(response) {
>     return response.json();
>   })
>   .then(function(myJson) {
>     console.log(myJson);
>   });
> ```

`response.json()` gives you a promise.

You need a new `then` function to get the value out of it.

Comment: @RonnWilder — [The documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) says: The json() method of the Body mixin takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. **It returns a promise** that resolves with the result of parsing the body text as JSON.

Comment: @RonnWilder — The OP said that `var json = response.json();
console.log(json);` gave `//It gives 'Promise {<resolved>: {…}}'` — i.e. **a promise**